# ArrayList[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to ArrayList<String>[]

Tags: java

I have this line of code:

```
ArrayList<String>[] rows = new ArrayList[size];
```

IDE(Eclipse give me this warning:

> Type safety: The expression of type ArrayList[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to ArrayList[]

What exactly should I do to fix this?

I need an fixed Array of unsized Lists.

Comment: There is no way to really fix that without a `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")`.

Comment: Use `ArrayList<String>[] rows = new ArrayList<>[size];`

Comment: Why not use  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> instead of ArrayList<String>[] ?